# Replace strings like \a25 in a string

Tags: java, regex, unicode, hex

I have a text that has some special characters in it, for example:

```
Nur bei guter \U25berwachung k\o25rperliche Belastung pr\u25fen und Sie entsprechend
```

I have a table that maps those to german umlauts; encoded as hexadecimal unicode letters. I'm trying to replace them in the text but am failing hard...

The desired output is `Ü` for \U25, `ö` for \025 an `ü` for \u25.

I've tried many things, as a example

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\\\[0-9A-Za-z]{3})", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(v);
String replacement = "00FB";
while (matcher.find()) {
    String match = matcher.group();
    int hexToInt = Integer.parseInt(replacement, 16);
    v = matcher.replaceFirst("" + hexToInt);
}
```

using the last line `v = matcher.replaceFirst(match, "Ü");` makes my program hang forever. I also tried `str.replace()` methods, to no avail...

Some of the characters:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your `replaceFirst` invocation will not compile as is...

Comment: Sorry and thanks @Mena, that was from the str.replace....

Comment: no probs. Do you only need to replace those 3 entities?

Comment: No, those are thousands. It's a huge amount of data... @Mena

Comment: Hhm. I'm not a crack at encodings in general but I'm not sure what the conversion rule is here. Is it basically `[vowel] + [25 for uhmlaut]`? And are there other types of diacritics et al. you need converted?

Comment: @Mena apparently you're much better at encodings than me.. I'm sitting in front of this without a clue, but that seems like a rule, yes... :)

Comment: Haha thanks. As per your edit, it seems like there's some conversion grid in place. Unfortunately I don't know myself what the values you currently have correspond to in terms of encoding, and mapping all those values by hand looks like a massive headache and possibly a futile exercise. Maybe someone can figure out where that `[letter] + [digits]` encoding comes from and if there's any built-in way to convert it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, this encoding is not a standard one. You can achieve it "neatly" like this though:

```
private static Map<String, String> CONVERSIONS = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("\\U25", "Ü");
    put("\\o25", "ö");
    put("\\u25", "ü");
}};

private static String convert(String str) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> conversion : CONVERSIONS.entrySet()) {
        str = str.replace(conversion.getKey(), conversion.getValue());
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note that you shouldn't use the regex-based `replaceAll()` - just use the plain-text matching `replace()` method (which still replaces all occurrences).

And then to use simply:

```
String str = convert("Nur bei guter \\U25berwachung k\\o25rperliche Belastung pr\\u25fen und Sie entsprechend");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Nur bei guter Überwachung körperliche Belastung prüfen und Sie entsprechend
```

I have used in-line initialization of the map, but you could easily adapt the initialization of the map to be done by reading in a properties or csv or similar file, which would make the whole thing quite easily managed.

Comment: Thank you. This is quite close to what I did now. I extracted the mappings from a pdf and saved them to redis. Now it starts to work.. :)